# How to get a DirectoryEntry from LDAP over SSL?

Tags: c#, ssl, active-directory

I'm trying to get the root DirectoryEntry from LDAP so I can show a nice graphical tree view of it.

It all works beautifully under normal connections but I can't get it to work with SSL.

```
var root = this.checkBoxSSL.Checked
                    ? new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + this.textBoxServer.Text,
                        this.textBoxUsername.Text,
                        this.textBoxPassword.Text,
                        AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer)
                    : new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + this.textBoxServer.Text,
                        this.textBoxUsername.Text,
                        this.textBoxPassword.Text);
var dn = root.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value;
```

And so on...

But I get a "Server not operational" exception. It all seems to go down to the bind process. Based on internet research it might be a problem with the certificate and/or the Authentication method (NTLM, etc).

**So how can I get a working DirectoryEntry over SSL?**

*I am open to alternative solutions, as long as I can retrieve all the LDAP Properties of the nodes I need. (Root, DC, OU, CN, Groups and Users)*

**EDIT:** As it seems the problem comes down to the SSL certificate. We only have a self-signed cert atm. And this seems to be rejected by .NET by default. We're going to try this with a properly signed cert later on but it's likely I need to be able to handle selfsigned ones too.

This is where my knowledge about certificates has limits. I'm currently exploring a different code solution because it seems to be the only one that allows me to influence the whole certificate handling:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2();
cert.Import("..\\..\\test certificate.cer");

LdapConnection con = new LdapConnection("ip:636");
con.Credential = new NetworkCredential("un", "pw");
con.AuthType = AuthType.Ntlm;
con.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
con.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((ldapcon, cer) => {
    var cer2 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(cer);

    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();

    strb.AppendFormat("{0} {1} matches: {2}\n", "Subject", cert.Subject, cert.Subject.Equals(cer2.Subject));
    strb.AppendFormat("{0} {1} matches: {2}\n", "Cert Hash", cert.GetCertHashString(), Enumerable.SequenceEqual<byte>(cer.GetCertHash(), cert.GetCertHash()));
    strb.AppendFormat("{0} matches: {2}\n", "Public Key", cert.GetPublicKeyString(), Enumerable.SequenceEqual<byte>(cer.GetPublicKey(), cert.GetPublicKey()));
    strb.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}, {2}", "Verification", cert.Verify(), cer2.Verify());

    var res = MessageBox.Show(strb.ToString(),
        "Allow certificate?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    return res == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes;
});

con.Bind();
```

Essentially, if that VerifyServerCertificateCallback returns true then the connection succeeds, if it returns falls the connection fails with the same exception as with any other solution I've tried.

Curiously, neither installing the AD certificate or the root certificate of the AD controller didn't help the other solutions but it does change the result of the Verify() method.

**What kind of checks do I have to perform on the certificate in the callback to maintain the sanctity of the SSL connection?**

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: @Markus Yes I more or less did. But since I don't work there anymore I'm going to have to respond from memory. In essence it turned out that I had to use two different LDAP Libraries depending on whether I needed SSL or not. I couldn't get LdapConnection to work with SSL and the newer .net library refused to work in non-SSL.

Comment: Ok, and the "new" .net lib, is that the `LDAPConnection` you have here in your last example?

Comment: @Markus: Right. LDAPConnection is the new one and DirectoryEntry was the old one.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to use `PrincipalContext` from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. The initialization would look like this:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(
            ContextType.Domain, NAME_OF_THE_DOMAIN + ":636", 
            null, 
            ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.Negotiate, 
            this.textBoxUsername.Text, 
            this.textBoxPassword.Text);
```

After that you can search for a `UserPrincipal` and its `DistinguishedName`:

```
string dn = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, this.textBoxUsername.Text).DistinguishedName;
```

If you want to itterate through the AD-tree just do something like this with the help of the `PrincipalSearcher`:

```
using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
{
    foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

        //DO watherever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not (just) trying to look up an account or group. I need to walk the entrie AD-Tree. Can I do that with this approach?

Comment: @Kempeth: of course - once you have a `PrincipalContext` that's properly authenticated via SSL, you can do anything with it - find users, create users, etc.

Comment: I don't think there's any benefit to using the `PrincipalContext`/`PrincipalSearcher` just to retrieve `DirectoryEntry` objects as shown in the example...

Comment: Thanks. But I'm getting a PrincipalServerDownException when I try to do this.

Comment: Maybe you should check the domain name: example: "Mydomain.local". It's not the servername.

Answer (score 7):

Brian Desmond was almost there.
You need to set 2 flags in DirectoryEntry AuthenticationType:

AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.Secure

example:

```
new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + this.textBoxServer.Text + ":636",
                    this.textBoxUsername.Text,
                    this.textBoxPassword.Text,
                    AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
```

Comment: +1 confirmed for me as well - `AuthenticationTypes` is a `[flag]`. Need to set both `SecureSocketsLayer` and `Secure` for this to work properly.

Comment: Apparently port 3269 is recommended over port 636.  https://www.nogalis.com/2020/05/18/why-you-shouldnt-use-port-636-to-bind-to-ldap-signing/

Answer (score 5):

At first, you should make sure you account and password is avaliable. use ldp.exe tool to check the account is avaliable.

then maybe you can try like below, please use LDAP:// not LDAPS://

```
LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection("xx1.bb.aa.com:636");
var op = conn.SessionOptions;
op.ProtocolVersion = 3;
op.SecureSocketLayer = true;
op.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };

conn.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
var cred = new NetworkCredential("accountname", "password");

//conn.Credential = cred;
try
{
    conn.Bind(cred);

    if (op.SecureSocketLayer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SSL for encryption is enabled - SSL information:");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    throw;
}
```

OR:

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xx1.bb.aa.com:636",
    "ldapsusername", "password", AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer);

//directoryEntry.Options

DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry)
{
    PageSize = int.MaxValue,
    Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=hp.wang))"
};

searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");

var result = searcher.FindOne();

if (result == null)
{
    return; // Or whatever you need to do in this case
}

string surname;

if (result.Properties.Contains("sn"))
{
    surname = result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: That works! Two comments:
**1.** I don't have to set `636` port. Just use the regular `"LDAP://xx1.bb.aa.com"`
**2.** To authorize as the current thread user (App Pool user in my case) use:
`new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://xx1.bb.aa.com", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.Secure);`

Comment: I am able to connect using the LdapConnection as show up top but when I try with the DirectoryEntry in the second snippet, I get a "Server is not operational" error.  I have tried with and without the port.  Same results.  Any ideas?

Comment: not using LDAPS: hint, has saved me :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe all you need to do is tweak this snippet to target the correct port (generally 636):

```
new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + this.textBoxServer.Text + ":636",
                        this.textBoxUsername.Text,
                        this.textBoxPassword.Text,
                        AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer)
```

Comment: If tried that but still get a "Server not operational" exception